# Multiple parallel routes with 404 route in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is the **working** example routing in my application where:

- `<AuthProvider />` is consumed at multiple places inside `<AuthRoute />` based components.
- `<AuthRoute />` is a just a wrapper around `<Route />` component that does some logic related to user auth

```
...
<Router history={history}>
  <AuthProvider>
    <Switch>
    <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
    <AuthRoute path='/account' exact component={MyAccount} />
    ...
    <Route path='*' exact component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </AuthProvider>
</Router>
...
```

Now that I don't like simple beautiful working application anymore, I have introduced something for users to do using tokens. Therefore updated version introduces the parallel routing as follows:

```
...
<Router history={history}>
  <TokenProvider>
    <Switch>
      <TokenRoute path='/blabla' exact component={TokenizedStuff} />
    </Switch>
  </TokenProvider>

  <AuthProvider>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
      <AuthRoute path='/account' exact component={MyAccount} />
      ...
      <Route path='*' exact component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </AuthProvider>
</Router>
...
```

**Problem**
Visiting the `/blabla` route renders the `<TokenizedStuff />` as well as `<NotFound />`.

I thought it might be because there are two lower level `<Switch />` so I brought them up as following:

```
...
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <TokenProvider>
      <TokenRoute path='/blabla' exact component={TokenizedStuff} />
    </TokenProvider>

    <AuthProvider>
      <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
      <AuthRoute path='/account' exact component={MyAccount} />
      ...
      <Route path='*' exact component={NotFound} />
    </AuthProvider>
  </Switch>
</Router>
...
```

That has now fixed the above issue but **created another problem**. Typical!

Now visiting `/account` route does not render anything. After inspecting the React devTools I found out that it works out the components tree into the `<TokenProvider />` and stops there.

I could combine the routes into one routing file and wrap with multiple providers to check for stuff and work it out but I would rather keep it tidy and readable for other team members now and joining in future.

Comment: It looks like that outer switch isn't really doing anything, you could wrap the provider tags with their own route to toggle between the two if you don't want both at the same time?  You could have a base route fro the token provider section and fallback to the auth provider.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I agree that top level Switch might not do anything but that was just a silly attempt – taking that Route has to be direct child of Switch in order to work properly. 

Could you provide a pseudo example of your suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be able to achieve what you're after using **nested routes**:

A pseudo example as discussed in comments:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/token' exact={false} component={TokenProvider} />
    <Route path='/' exact={false} component={AuthProvider} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

The top level routes set out a higher level branching point for your application, then you can have additional routing logic within child components. There will be multiple solutions you can develop using this technique.

I find this is a more scalable way of managing routes within larger applications, rather than having a single, ever growing `routes` component.

[This](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/) blog post provides a nice summary and explains some good practices (E.g. using `match.path` to construct child routes).

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I will give it some thought and revert.

Comment: @JabranRafique Did you get sorted with this?

Comment: Oliver, unfortunately I had to take a different approach, not ideal but I had to use the TokenProvider as HOC as I did not have liberty to use routes with prefix paths as suggested. Though I would recommend this approach to anyone starting from scratch in a project.

Comment: Here is what I finally went for:

```
...
<Router history={history}>
  <TokenProvider>
    <AuthProvider>
      <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
      <AuthRoute path='/account' exact component={MyAccount} />
      <TokenRoute path='/blabla' exact component={TokenizedStuff} />
      ...
      <Route path='*' exact component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </AuthProvider>
  </TokenProvider>
</Router>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally went for:

```
...
<Router history={history}>
  <TokenProvider>
    <AuthProvider>
      <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
      <AuthRoute path='/account' exact component={MyAccount} />
      <TokenRoute path='/blabla' exact component={TokenizedStuff} />
      ...
      <Route path='*' exact component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </AuthProvider>
  </TokenProvider>
</Router>
...
```

Where **TokenRoute** takes care of all **tokenized stuff** and **AuthRoute** takes care of all **auth based stuff**. The best thing I found this way was that these particular handling will only come in action when a particular route is matched otherwise it is ignored.

Oliver's given approach is also another good way to separate the concerns but that was difficult to implement in an existing large scale application. It would be a good start point for any small/new application.